# Run function / pipeline after a pipeline completes on Google DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a function (or a pipeline) after a Beam pipeline completes, on Google DataFlow.

Currently I've built a hack to run the function by writing the results of the previous Pipeline to `null` with

```
_ = existing_pipeline | "do next task" >> beam.Map(func)
```

...where func is:

```
def func(_):
    # do some work, and ignore `_`
```

But is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the function to run on your machine and not in the Cloud, you should do something like this:

```
result = existing_pipeline.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
# do some work
```